# Associate 'application data' with existing IO object

Tags: ruby

I've got a class:

```
class MyProgram
    attr_reader :control_socket

    def initialize
        @control_socket = UNIXSocket.new('path/to/socket')
        ...
    end

    def read_message
        ...
    end
end
```

and I'd like to select on multiple instances of that program like so:

```
# Does not work
programs = [my_pgm1, my_pgm2]
io_wrappers = programs.collect { |p| wrap(p) }
r, w, err = select(programs)
r.each { |pgm|
    pgm.my_program.read_message
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to wrap the UNIXSocket to associate a `MyProgram` with it.

Comment: Comments please, on why downvote, close.

Comment: I don't want MyProgram to inherit from IO really, bu have a way to get  an associated instance of MyProgram from an IO object passed to select (without using a hash of IO to MyProgram instance). I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about keeping a map from your sockets back to their respective programs?

```
programs = [my_pgm1, my_pgm2]
sockets = Hash[programs.map { |p| [p.control_socket, p] }
r, w, err = select(sockets.keys)
r.each { |socket|
    sockets[socket].read_message
}
```

---

**Update:**

I did not test this, but you could try creating an explicit conversion:

```
class MyProgram
  def to_io
    control_socket
  end
end

programs = [my_pgm1, my_pgm2]
r, w, err = select(programs)
r.each { |pgm|
    pgm.read_message
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. Probably my poor understanding of ruby, but I'd thought that there'd be a way to avoid the extra hash lookup using duck typing?

Comment: Yes! exactly what I was looking for. Where is `to_io` documented? This is the first I'm seeing of it.

Comment: Actually, I was not familiar with this either, I _extrapolated_ on `to_s`, `to_i`, etc... I guess it's the ruby way... :-)

Comment: Good guess! I wouldn't have expected it. Thanks!